# Как использовать TabBar в Swift со множеством зависимых viewController'ов у root?

Tags: ios, swift, tab

Получаю черный экран при переключении с экранов первой вкладки (Start) и обратно. На других вкладках всего по одному зависимому контроллеру и такого не происходит.
Kind of segue - Show (e.g. Push)

Переходы между контроллерами осуществляются через performSegue(withIdentifier: )

Не понимаю в чем может быть проблема. Прошу помочь разобраться.

P.s. контроллеры при этом остаются в памяти

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    var sender = String()
    if let text = searchController.searchBar.text {
        sender = text
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToWebView", sender: sender)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToWebView" {
        let company = sender as! String
        let dvc = segue.destination as! SearchRequestReviewVC
        dvc.searchPhrase = company
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая ситуация возникла из-за присутствия активного searchController'a на одном из ViewController'ов в иерархии переходов.

Решением послужила следующая строка во viewController с searchController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

Также можно добавить в иерархию переходов UINavigationController между контроллерами.

> Из документации: когда UIKit встречает значение true, то он спрашивает
>   у текущего контроллера, какой контроллер показывать следующим. 
>   UINavigationController меняет дефолтное значение (false) в true.

т.е. как я понял search в активном состояний каким-то образом препятствуют назначения следующего контроллера контроллером представления контекста.

Очень помог следующий пост на StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445837/what-are-definespresentationcontext-and-providespresentationcontexttransitionsty

И документация: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621456-definespresentationcontext

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]